# Nested Form: unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

So I am new to Rails and I have been trying to build a nested form. I have been having a lot of trouble and can't seem to get it to work.. I have watched multiple videos on youtube but I can't seem to find what I am doing different. For the purpose of me trying to build one, I have a Product which has many Buyers but a Buyer belongs to only one Product. (Assume you can only buy one Product...). When I submit my form I get an error which I can see in the server log: **"Unpermitted parameter: buyer"** I feel like I have tried everything.. I'd be so happy if someone could maybe tell me whats going on. Thanks so much

I have followed the Rails guide and added the following to my models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
  has_many :buyers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buyers          
end


class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product                        
end
```

Strong Params in the Product Controller:

```
  def product_params
   params.require(:product).permit(:name, :description, :image_url, :color, :adult, buyers_attributes: [:name, :age, :product_id])
  end
```

And the Products controller:

```
 def new
@product = Product.new
@product.buyers.build     end
```

Then for the form:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYUHG.png)
(Sorry, was having major issues inserting the code here)

Lastly this my schema for both tables:

```
  create_table "buyers", force: :cascade do |t|

t.string   "name"

t.integer  "age"

t.datetime "created_at", null: false

t.datetime "updated_at", null: false

t.integer  "product_id"   end
```

```
`
```

create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|

t.string   "name"

t.text     "description"

t.string   "image_url"

t.string   "color"

t.datetime "created_at",  null: false

t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false

t.integer  "price"

t.binary   "adult"        
 end

Comment: I think you need id in the buyers_attributes array

Comment: I already tried that with both :product_id and :id   :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your product acceptes nested attributes for `buyers` but you're only adding buyer (no plural) attributes to the form.  You probably need to change the nested form to

```
<%= f.fields_for :buyers, [@product.buyers.build] do |x| %>
```

Comment: Ah, finally... I had tried that before but I guess something else was wrong at that point... Now it works. Thank you so very much, highly appreciate your time

Comment: He seems to have forgotten you, have a +1 from me

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Thanks again